# rename multiple files

Tags: linux, windows, unix, rename, file-rename

I have multiple file like :

```
abc_e1000g1.pcap.1
abc_e1000g1.pcap.2
```

I have to rename this to

```
1abc_e1000g1.pcap
2abc_e1000g1.pcap
```

Any unix / dos command for this.

Comment: was searching on net but i got to rename multiple files for extension (like .txt etc)....but here i need to rename ext as well as name of the file.

Comment: http://www.lagmonster.org/docs/DOS7/z-ren1.html#numseries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there are shorter ways do to this, but here's what comes naturally, using unix shell, assuming there's nothing but the files of interest in your present working directory:

```
for i in *; do mv "$i" "$(echo $i | sed 's/\(.*\)\.\(.*\)/\2\1/')"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this PowerShell Command would work for you.

```
dir | rename-item -newName { $_.Name -replace '^(.+)\.([0-9]+)$', '$2$1' }
```